# How to return from a enum the correct type so can be used from a function in sample data

Tags: swift

Im trying to tell my model to return a string for the enum type so I can set my image properly on the front end. I am quite new to swift and swift ui coming from a Csharp background.

```
struct PlayerRankingViewModel : Identifiable {
var id: UUID
var PlayerId : Int
var RankingType : Int
var RankingTypeImage : String
var FirstName:String
var LastName : String
var Reps: Decimal
var Weight: Decimal
var Seconds:Decimal
var DistanceFt:Decimal
var DistanceInches:Decimal

enum RankingTypes :Int{
    case BAH = 1
    case PU     = 2
    case TB = 3
    case BP = 4
    case OP = 5
    case PUH = 6
    case Bike = 7
    case TwentyFiveYard = 8
    case OneFiftyYard = 9
    case Jumps = 10
    case VJ = 11
    case BroadJump = 12
    case FrontSquat = 13
    case HangClean = 14
}

init(id: UUID = UUID()  ,PlayerId:Int,RankingType:Int,RankingTypeImage:String,
FirstName:String,LastName:String, Reps:Decimal,  
Weight:Decimal,Seconds:Decimal,DistanceFt:Decimal,
DistanceInches:Decimal){
    
    self.id = id
    self.PlayerId = PlayerId
    self.RankingType = RankingType
    self.RankingTypeImage = ConvertExerciseTypeToImage(by: RankingType)
    self.FirstName = FirstName
    self.LastName = LastName
    self.Reps = Reps
    self.Weight = Weight
    self.Seconds=Seconds
    self.DistanceFt = DistanceFt
    self.DistanceInches = DistanceInches
    
}
```

This Is function doing the conversation

```
func ConvertExerciseTypeToImage(by ExerciseType: Int) -> String   {
       
    if(ExerciseType == RankingTypes.Bike.rawValue)
    {
        return("bicycle")
        
    }
    
}}
```

My Main Question is how do I pass that in my sample data section

```
extension PlayerRankingViewModel {
 static var sampleData : [PlayerRankingViewModel] {
 [
  
   PlayerRankingViewModel(PlayerId:2,RankingType:RankingTypes.BP.rawValue,
        RankingTypeImage What Do I put here??  : ,FirstName: "Dazy",
        LastName:"Johnstone" ,Reps: 56.39, Weight:
        125.00,Seconds:0.00,DistanceFt:0.00,DistanceInches:0.00)
 ]
```

As you see am not to sure how I place the value into the RankingTypeImage or is this the best way to achieve this should I just return an image. I guess am looking for best practise for type convertors, I come form a sharp background.

Its so on the front end I can display an image based on what exercise the student is doing?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the conversion right in the enum

```
enum RankingTypes: Int {
    case BAH = 1, PU, TB, BP, OP, PUH, Bike, TwentyFiveYard
    case OneFiftyYard, Jumps, VJ, BroadJump, FrontSquat, HangClean

    var stringValue : String {
        switch self {
            ...
            case .Bike: return "bicycle"
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Please consider the Swift naming convention that variables, functions and enum cases start with a lowercase letter.

In the enum the subsequent integer values are inferred after specifying the first one

Comment: How would I access that in the sample data then ? that's the bit I'm struggling with as well as pointed out on OQ. I tried that it said that the switch must be exaustive I presume that means just must all be filled in

Comment: `RankingTypes.BP.stringValue`. And of course you have to return a string value for each case in a new line.

Comment: Thanks very much just learning the ropes not to different to csharp but enough to get the job done